# ignoring the files not more than 1 row in entire file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I am facing an issue with the below code. Below script will count the delimiters (comma, pipe or semicolon) in the 2nd row and 3rd row of the files. If the count is not matching in the 2nd and 3rd rows, the files will move to the rejected folder. But the problem is, for some file there is only one row, there the script is not moving forward. How can I add a line to the below script to ignore if the files has not more than 1 row.

```
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/inbox

findresult=$(find $pathname -type f ( -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" ))


Count=`sed -n 2p $findresult | tr '[,]' '\n' | tr '[|]' '\n' | tr '[;]' '\n' | wc -l`
Count2=`sed -n 3p $findresult | tr '[,]' '\n' | tr '[|]' '\n' | tr '[;]' '\n' | wc -l`

echo $Count
echo $Count2
    #if the delimiter count from the 2nd line and 3rd line doesnt match the    file will move to the rejected folder
if [ $Count != $Count2 ]

then echo "Mis Match"

 mv $findresult /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/reject
else echo "Match"
 exit
fi
```

Comment: Hi Allan, yes I just now did, please check and let me know if I didnt do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if clause is not written properly, for integer comparison you should use the syntax:

```
if [ "$count" -ne "$count2" ]
```

You can also change your `sed/tr` commands in:

```
Count=`sed -n '2y/,;|/\n\n\n/;p' $findresult | wc -l`
Count2=`sed -n '3y/,;|/\n\n\n/;p' $findresult | wc -l`
```

instead of using that many pipes `y` command will do the translation.

Also you will need to put everything in a loop as you want to process one file after another:

```
for f in `find $pathname -type f ( -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" )`
do

 Count=`sed -n '2y/,;|/\n\n\n/;p' "$f" | wc -l`
 Count2=`sed -n '3y/,;|/\n\n\n/;p' "$f" | wc -l`

 echo $Count
 echo $Count2
    #if the delimiter count from the 2nd line and 3rd line doesnt match the    file will move to the rejected folder
 if [ "$Count" -ne "$Count2" ]
 then 
  echo "Mis Match"
  mv "$f" /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/reject
 else 
  echo "Match"
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your complete requirement, could you please change your find command with this find command which should give files which are having more than 1 lines.

```
find $pathname -type f \( -name "file*" -or -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" \) -exec bash -c '[[ $(wc -l < "$1") -gt 1 ]] && echo "cat $1"' _ '{}' \;
```

You could place this in your variable and then you need not to check any condition you could simply run your commands on output of this command or so.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I tried the above script, but somehow the script is keep running for several minutes and not moving forward. Could you please take a look again.

Comment: @KiranChapidi, when I run `find $pathname -type f \( -name "file*" -or -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" \) -exec bash -c '[[ $(wc -l < "$1") -gt 1 ]] && echo "$1"' _ '{}' \;` it is running fine for me, I had little amount of files so it given file names in few mili seconds itself, how about you?

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Here I tried like this       `findresult=$(find $pathname -type f ( -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" )) -exec bash -c '[[ $(wc -l < "$1") -gt 1 ]] && echo "$1"' _ '{}' \;` because I need findresult parameter to call it in the next line of the code.

Comment: @KiranChapidi, agreed. can you simply run that command on terminal once to same directory and see how much it is taking?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/[^,;|]//g;s/././g;2h;3{G;/^(.*)\n\1$/!q1}' file && 
echo match || (echo mismatch; mv file rejectDir)
```

From each line, remove any character that does not represent a newline then convert those character left to periods. Compare the length of the second and third lines, and if they are not the same, quit with a exit code of 1 otherwise quit with an exit code o f zero.

Use bash to recognise the preceding exit code.